# rlm_rest serving TTLS PAP

Tags: android, django, freeradius

I'm trying writing a django based service to serve FreeRadius rlm_rest.

Currently, it's succes on :
 1. Serving FreeRadius DHCP
 2. Serving Authorization for PPPoE NAS, using only PAP, including set user IP-Address, Default Route Gateway and DNS server.

but it Fail serving user using Android Wifi with TTLS-PAP.

What user's gadget got is :
 1. Looks like authenticated, but ...
 2. keep in 'Optaining IP Address' state for some minutes ..... and Fail.

Radius Debug (freeradius -X -x)

```
Tue Oct 11 04:59:00 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: JSON Data: {"User-Name":{"type":"string","value":["dokter01"]},"User-Password":{"type":"string","value":["dr123456"]},"NAS-IP-Address":{"type":"ipaddr","value":["10.255.255.12"]},"Service-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[2]},"Framed-MTU":{"type":"integer","value":[1400]},"Called-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["00-0C-42-CF-16-55:ojoliwatkene"]},"Calling-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["08-8C-2C-0D-84-67"]},"NAS-Identifier":{"type":"string","value":["apsi-metal"]},"NAS-Port-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[19]},"NAS-Port-Id":{"type":"string","value":["wlan1"]},"FreeRADIUS-Proxied-To":{"type":"ipaddr","value":["127.0.0.1"]}}
Tue Oct 11 04:59:00 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: Returning 631 bytes of JSON data
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: Processing response header
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Status : 200 (OK)
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Type   : json (application/json)
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: Parsing attribute "reply:Reply-Message"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Type   : string
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Length : 20
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Value  : "Welcomeback dokter01"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: Welcomeback dokter01
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: Parsed xlat tree:
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: literal --> Welcomeback dokter01
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: EXPAND Welcomeback dokter01
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:    --> Welcomeback dokter01
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: Reply-Message := "Welcomeback dokter01"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: Parsing attribute "reply:MS-Primary-DNS-Server"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Type   : ipaddr
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Length : 7
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Value  : "8.8.8.8"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: 8.8.8.8
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: Parsed xlat tree:
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: literal --> 8.8.8.8
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: EXPAND 8.8.8.8
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:    --> 8.8.8.8
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: MS-Primary-DNS-Server := 8.8.8.8
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: Parsing attribute "reply:Framed-Route"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Type   : string
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Length : 22
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Value  : "0.0.0.0 10.255.3.126 1"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: 0.0.0.0 10.255.3.126 1
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: Parsed xlat tree:
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: literal --> 0.0.0.0 10.255.3.126 1
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: EXPAND 0.0.0.0 10.255.3.126 1
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:    --> 0.0.0.0 10.255.3.126 1
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: Framed-Route := "0.0.0.0 10.255.3.126 1"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: Parsing attribute "reply:Framed-IP-Address"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Type   : ipaddr
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Length : 10
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Value  : "10.255.3.7"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: 10.255.3.7
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: Parsed xlat tree:
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: literal --> 10.255.3.7
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: EXPAND 10.255.3.7
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:    --> 10.255.3.7
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: Framed-IP-Address := 10.255.3.7
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: Parsing attribute "control:Cleartext-Password"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Type   : string
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Length : 8
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Value  : "dr123456"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: dr123456
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: Parsed xlat tree:
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: literal --> dr123456
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: EXPAND dr123456
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:    --> dr123456
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: Cleartext-Password := "dr123456"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: Parsing attribute "reply:Framed-IP-Netmask"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Type   : ipaddr
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Length : 15
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:   Value  : "255.255.255.128"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: 255.255.255.128
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: Parsed xlat tree:
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: literal --> 255.255.255.128
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: EXPAND 255.255.255.128
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest:    --> 255.255.255.128
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) rest: Framed-IP-Netmask := 255.255.255.128
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: rlm_rest (rest): Released connection (14)
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)       modsingle[authorize]: returned from rest (rlm_rest) for request 34
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)       [rest] = updated
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)       modsingle[authorize]: calling pap (rlm_pap) for request 34
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)       modsingle[authorize]: returned from pap (rlm_pap) for request 34
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)       [pap] = updated
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)     } # authorize = updated
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   Found Auth-Type = PAP
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)     Auth-Type PAP {
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)       modsingle[authenticate]: calling pap (rlm_pap) for request 34
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) pap: Login attempt with password "dr123456" (8)
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) pap: Comparing with "known good" Cleartext-Password "dr123456" (8)
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) pap: User authenticated successfully
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)       modsingle[authenticate]: returned from pap (rlm_pap) for request 34
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)       [pap] = ok
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)     } # Auth-Type PAP = ok
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   # Executing section post-auth from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)     post-auth { ... } # empty sub-section is ignored
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) } # server inner-tunnel
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) Virtual server sending reply
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   Reply-Message = "Welcomeback dokter01"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   MS-Primary-DNS-Server = 8.8.8.8
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   Framed-Route = "0.0.0.0 10.255.3.126 1"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   Framed-IP-Address = 10.255.3.7
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   Framed-IP-Netmask = 255.255.255.128
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) eap_ttls: Got tunneled Access-Accept
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) eap_ttls: No information to cache: session caching will be disabled for session 96337f55209ded31a591d3c14193a65eb196bedd3de584248ce75d2521f385dc
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) eap: Sending EAP Success (code 3) ID 6 length 4
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) eap: Freeing handler
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)     modsingle[authenticate]: returned from eap (rlm_eap) for request 34
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)     [eap] = ok
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   } # authenticate = ok
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) # Executing section post-auth from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   post-auth {
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)     update {
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)       No attributes updated
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)     } # update = noop
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)     modsingle[post-auth]: calling exec (rlm_exec) for request 34
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)     modsingle[post-auth]: returned from exec (rlm_exec) for request 34
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)     [exec] = noop
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)       else {
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)         modsingle[post-auth]: calling noop (rlm_always) for request 34
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)         modsingle[post-auth]: returned from noop (rlm_always) for request 34
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)         [noop] = noop
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)       } # else = noop
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   } # post-auth = noop
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) Sent Access-Accept Id 7 from 10.255.255.14:1812 to 10.255.255.12:38015 length 0
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   MS-MPPE-Recv-Key = 0x6b1fdb4ab629866ff09d04b101d2594b91e5afd3fdcf218ef7d8eaee66864e4b
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   MS-MPPE-Send-Key = 0x5480836c212cda13264ab61b6385529d907332e4dfbc045b9c6c8255847e697f
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   EAP-Message = 0x03060004
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34)   User-Name = "dokter01"
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: (34) Finished request
Tue Oct 11 04:59:01 2016 : Debug: Waking up in 3.5 seconds.
Tue Oct 11 04:59:04 2016 : Debug: (28) Cleaning up request packet ID 1 with timestamp +1116
Tue Oct 11 04:59:04 2016 : Debug: (29) Cleaning up request packet ID 2 with timestamp +1116
Tue Oct 11 04:59:04 2016 : Debug: Waking up in 1.0 seconds.
Tue Oct 11 04:59:05 2016 : Debug: (31) Cleaning up request packet ID 4 with timestamp +1117
Tue Oct 11 04:59:05 2016 : Debug: (32) Cleaning up request packet ID 5 with timestamp +1117
Tue Oct 11 04:59:05 2016 : Debug: (33) Cleaning up request packet ID 6 with timestamp +1117
Tue Oct 11 04:59:05 2016 : Debug: Waking up in 0.2 seconds.
Tue Oct 11 04:59:06 2016 : Debug: (34) Cleaning up request packet ID 7 with timestamp +1117
Tue Oct 11 04:59:06 2016 : Debug: Waking up in 4.5 seconds.
Tue Oct 11 04:59:10 2016 : Debug: (30) Cleaning up request packet ID 3 with timestamp +1116
Tue Oct 11 04:59:10 2016 : Info: Ready to process requests
```

Rest Service (django) debug :

```
October 11, 2016 - 04:58:40
Django version 1.10.2, using settings 'djrad.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Request Body: {"User-Name":{"type":"string","value":["dokter01"]},"NAS-IP-Address":{"type":"ipaddr","value":["10.255.255.12"]},"Service-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[2]},"Framed-MTU":{"type":"integer","value":[1400]},"Called-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["00-0C-42-CF-16-55:ojoliwatkene"]},"Calling-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["08-8C-2C-0D-84-67"]},"NAS-Identifier":{"type":"string","value":["apsi-metal"]},"NAS-Port-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[19]},"EAP-Message":{"type":"octets","value":["0x0200000d01646f6b7465723031"]},"Message-Authenticator":{"type":"octets","value":["0x3f282027fb2d0ccb873193e81889f65a"]},"NAS-Port-Id":{"type":"string","value":["wlan1"]}}
serverSite: default
radSection: authorize
ReturnJSON--> {}
[11/Oct/2016 04:58:59] "POST /hotspot/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2

Request Body: {"User-Name":{"type":"string","value":["dokter01"]},"NAS-IP-Address":{"type":"ipaddr","value":["10.255.255.12"]},"Service-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[2]},"Framed-MTU":{"type":"integer","value":[1400]},"State":{"type":"octets","value":["0x09568216095786c7dae9fd736c15bac2"]},"Called-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["00-0C-42-CF-16-55:ojoliwatkene"]},"Calling-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["08-8C-2C-0D-84-67"]},"NAS-Identifier":{"type":"string","value":["apsi-metal"]},"NAS-Port-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[19]},"EAP-Message":{"type":"octets","value":["0x020100060315"]},"Message-Authenticator":{"type":"octets","value":["0x66e678488e03f58ea92d708c7b1a03b7"]},"NAS-Port-Id":{"type":"string","value":["wlan1"]}}
serverSite: default
radSection: authorize
ReturnJSON--> {}
[11/Oct/2016 04:58:59] "POST /hotspot/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2

Request Body: {"User-Name":{"type":"string","value":["dokter01"]},"NAS-IP-Address":{"type":"ipaddr","value":["10.255.255.12"]},"Service-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[2]},"Framed-MTU":{"type":"integer","value":[1400]},"State":{"type":"octets","value":["0x09568216085497c7dae9fd736c15bac2"]},"Called-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["00-0C-42-CF-16-55:ojoliwatkene"]},"Calling-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["08-8C-2C-0D-84-67"]},"NAS-Identifier":{"type":"string","value":["apsi-metal"]},"NAS-Port-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[19]},"EAP-Message":{"type":"octets","value":["0x020200cc150016030100c1010000bd030157fc71936333a0ef337f2d32b760723a4675d7f8279fd7b03ddbf0e3a9fe38a5000054c014c00ac022c02100390038c00fc0050035c012c008c01cc01b00160013c00dc003000ac013c009c01fc01e00330032c00ec004002fc011c007c00cc002000500040015001200090014001100080006000300ff01000040000b000403000102000a00340032000e000d0019000b000c00180009000a00160017000800060007001400150004000500120013000100020003000f00100011"]},"Message-Authenticator":{"type":"octets","value":["0xbe5d032827520474122099b24359ea2c"]},"NAS-Port-Id":{"type":"string","value":["wlan1"]}}
serverSite: default
radSection: authorize
ReturnJSON--> {}
[11/Oct/2016 04:59:00] "POST /hotspot/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2

Request Body: {"User-Name":{"type":"string","value":["dokter01"]},"NAS-IP-Address":{"type":"ipaddr","value":["10.255.255.12"]},"Service-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[2]},"Framed-MTU":{"type":"integer","value":[1400]},"State":{"type":"octets","value":["0x095682160b5597c7dae9fd736c15bac2"]},"Called-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["00-0C-42-CF-16-55:ojoliwatkene"]},"Calling-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["08-8C-2C-0D-84-67"]},"NAS-Identifier":{"type":"string","value":["apsi-metal"]},"NAS-Port-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[19]},"EAP-Message":{"type":"octets","value":["0x020300061500"]},"Message-Authenticator":{"type":"octets","value":["0xd5ac2831939319e86d13fec44930658f"]},"NAS-Port-Id":{"type":"string","value":["wlan1"]}}
serverSite: default
radSection: authorize
ReturnJSON--> {}
[11/Oct/2016 04:59:00] "POST /hotspot/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2

Request Body: {"User-Name":{"type":"string","value":["dokter01"]},"NAS-IP-Address":{"type":"ipaddr","value":["10.255.255.12"]},"Service-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[2]},"Framed-MTU":{"type":"integer","value":[1400]},"State":{"type":"octets","value":["0x095682160a5297c7dae9fd736c15bac2"]},"Called-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["00-0C-42-CF-16-55:ojoliwatkene"]},"Calling-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["08-8C-2C-0D-84-67"]},"NAS-Identifier":{"type":"string","value":["apsi-metal"]},"NAS-Port-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[19]},"EAP-Message":{"type":"octets","value":["0x020400061500"]},"Message-Authenticator":{"type":"octets","value":["0x010cc31b7476cbcc7261f8d938ed5991"]},"NAS-Port-Id":{"type":"string","value":["wlan1"]}}
serverSite: default
radSection: authorize
ReturnJSON--> {}
[11/Oct/2016 04:59:00] "POST /hotspot/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2

Request Body: {"User-Name":{"type":"string","value":["dokter01"]},"NAS-IP-Address":{"type":"ipaddr","value":["10.255.255.12"]},"Service-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[2]},"Framed-MTU":{"type":"integer","value":[1400]},"State":{"type":"octets","value":["0x095682160d5397c7dae9fd736c15bac2"]},"Called-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["00-0C-42-CF-16-55:ojoliwatkene"]},"Calling-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["08-8C-2C-0D-84-67"]},"NAS-Identifier":{"type":"string","value":["apsi-metal"]},"NAS-Port-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[19]},"EAP-Message":{"type":"octets","value":["0x0205008c15001603010046100000424104c46976fcbafca4a5c4c79bbd810aad7ea28417188265f543fa158c6bbe62b3f0e2a95a8971f285436176e0e6a3f5d5f8ea8bf21db61c24c3e4fb6a856a11e2be14030100010116030100302d8ef81aecf7e16cda46dd05030818039487a5d5e70c2ada9d931ab92d73e1254b77a40f78ad3b05153d4222dbf421d4"]},"Message-Authenticator":{"type":"octets","value":["0xb59561f8088cb89671320104df3f3a1a"]},"NAS-Port-Id":{"type":"string","value":["wlan1"]}}
serverSite: default
radSection: authorize
ReturnJSON--> {}
[11/Oct/2016 04:59:00] "POST /hotspot/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2

Request Body: {"User-Name":{"type":"string","value":["dokter01"]},"NAS-IP-Address":{"type":"ipaddr","value":["10.255.255.12"]},"Service-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[2]},"Framed-MTU":{"type":"integer","value":[1400]},"State":{"type":"octets","value":["0x095682160c5097c7dae9fd736c15bac2"]},"Called-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["00-0C-42-CF-16-55:ojoliwatkene"]},"Calling-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["08-8C-2C-0D-84-67"]},"NAS-Identifier":{"type":"string","value":["apsi-metal"]},"NAS-Port-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[19]},"EAP-Message":{"type":"octets","value":["0x0206007015001703010020b021f6c7e508621666c169026011f58bf321cd60888c0cf25312525d4412f3631703010040c0b9248b3dca8a2899d675bed4949291d8b0d37017bfde8a0b6baccb692152ad17b4865891aac86f031500fba9bf48f6352d906e12f3246f6474c87545a2be9d"]},"Message-Authenticator":{"type":"octets","value":["0xb7fd8d6065b4db28f909c33dc759fca7"]},"NAS-Port-Id":{"type":"string","value":["wlan1"]}}
serverSite: default
radSection: authorize
ReturnJSON--> {}
[11/Oct/2016 04:59:00] "POST /hotspot/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2

Request Body: {"User-Name":{"type":"string","value":["dokter01"]},"User-Password":{"type":"string","value":["dr123456"]},"NAS-IP-Address":{"type":"ipaddr","value":["10.255.255.12"]},"Service-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[2]},"Framed-MTU":{"type":"integer","value":[1400]},"Called-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["00-0C-42-CF-16-55:ojoliwatkene"]},"Calling-Station-Id":{"type":"string","value":["08-8C-2C-0D-84-67"]},"NAS-Identifier":{"type":"string","value":["apsi-metal"]},"NAS-Port-Type":{"type":"integer","value":[19]},"NAS-Port-Id":{"type":"string","value":["wlan1"]},"FreeRADIUS-Proxied-To":{"type":"ipaddr","value":["127.0.0.1"]}}
serverSite: inner-tunnel
radSection: authorize
HSGROUP FILTER : {'name': 'dokter'}
HSPOOL FILTER : {'group': <HsGroup: dokter>, 'portal': <HsPortal: metal>}
HSLEASE FILTER : {'isstatic': False, 'isleased': False, 'pool': <HsPool: dokter@metal>}
ReturnJSON--> {'reply:Reply-Message': u'Welcomeback dokter01', 'reply:MS-Primary-DNS-Server': u'8.8.8.8', 'reply:Framed-Route': u'0.0.0.0 10.255.3.126 1', 'reply:Framed-IP-Address': u'10.255.3.7', 'control:Cleartext-Password': u'dr123456', 'reply:Framed-IP-Netmask': u'255.255.255.128'}
[11/Oct/2016 04:59:01] "POST /hotspot/ HTTP/1.1" 200 266
```

Comment: rlm_rest seems to be working fine... Problem is on the NAS.

Comment: dear @Arran Cudbard-Bell

My stupidity ....

I Just found that in TTLS-EAP not all 'Frammed-xxx-xxx' is recognized.

So the android client always send DHCP request after authenticated.

since my DHCP server also user the same FreeRadius engine and the same web-service , my workarround is : make a 'DHCP reservation' for authorized user ... put his/her mac address on my ip-pool object ... and it will be used when ever the device send DHCP-Discovery and DHCP-Request..

I really appreciate your response.

Thankyou